# SSMS 17.9 opens database on SQL Server 2014 instead of 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, ssms-2017

I have SQL Server 2014 and I did use it and have some db on it.
[image: this photo]

Yesterday I installed SQL Server Management Studio 17.9 and when I open it I just see the same db created on SQL Server 2014 (sql 12.0.2000.8).
[image: this photo]

But I want to create or restore some db that I created on SQL Server 2016 and I cant.

How should I tell SSMS 17.9 to use this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server2016\MSSQL13.SQL2016SQL2016\MSSQL
```

Here I installed 2016.
[image: this photo]

Comment: You should connect to `.\SQL2016SQL2016`, since apparently that's what you've named your SQL Server 2016 instance (you haven't upgraded the existing 2014 instance). If that's not it, use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to get your instances, and verify the service is actually running.

Comment: You can connect to any SQL Server version just fine. There's nothing wrong with SSMS. It doesn't affect the SQL Server instances, it's just a client application. You are still trying to connect to the 2014 instance version, not the 2016 instance you created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an instance named `SQL2016SQL2016`.
So you have to add the instance to the servername in the connection window like:

`localhost\SQL2016SQL2016`

> An instance of the Database Engine is a copy of the sqlservr.exe
>   executable that runs as an operating system service. Each instance
>   manages several system databases and one or more user databases. Each
>   computer can run multiple instances of the Database Engine.
>   Applications connect to the instance in order to perform work in a
>   database managed by the instance.

Source: [Database Engine Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)